# how to access PC from wan by domain

Tags: php, dns, wamp, host

i am accessing my wamp server from WAN through PC's IP address 122.xxx.xxx.xx. but now i want to access my wamp through DOMAIN name.
 i only have my domain name and no other credentials for setting. is it possible with domain name?

Comment: learn how to setup server to host websites...

Comment: you might also want to try free dynamic DNS services that attach your (possibly dynamic) IP address to a constant domain name. One example is dnsexit.com but there are others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to point your domain name at that ip address.  In your settings or admin panel where you setup/purchased your domain name set the ip address to the 122.xxx.xxx.xx you have been using.

Comment: i dont have any admin panel or settings. my domain provider not give me any thing. i only have domain name and a authorization code

Comment: That is like having a space in the phone book but you never told them what your home address is. Contact the domain name company or set up another domain name with a different company.

Answer (score 0):

This really depends upon your location.

If when you reboot your router you get a new WAN IP address every time, then you cannot use the domain name you have purchased. You would have to use a Dynamic DNS provider like DYNDNS.COM or Amnon's suggestion DNSEXIT.COM or one of the others that provide this service. With that service you will unfortunately have to use one of their sudo domain names, which means you will have to use something like YOURDOMAIN.ONE_OF_THEIR_DOMAINS.ONE_OF_THEIR_TLDS, so it would look like mydomain.dyndns.net  they normally have quite a few to choose from, but it wont look like www.yourdomain.com

If you always have the same WAN IP address for your router then you can use you purchased domain name. You will have to contact whoever you purchased it from, they would normally provide a web site where you can login and set the ip address you want to use for the domain name you have purchased. Once that is done and you give the DNS servers a few minutes to a few hours to get updated you will be able to use that domain name.